# Pressing "try it" button reloads the page

Tags: html

when I press a try it button at the bottom of my page, it reloads the page and deselects all checkboxes. THe main problem i have with this is that when i select a box and click total, the total will be displayed for a split second, before the page reloads back to a state of nothing being checked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrlgp.png)

Comment: what exactly is your problem? And can you provide any code for this page.

Comment: Could you edit the post to add a picture or maybe code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have the page reloaded, you can use event.preventDefault();. when you use the event prevent function, this function blocks reloading the page when clicking/pressing the "try it" button.

Answer (score 1):

Check type of button in your code. If you want to submit form data then only add `<input type="submit">` otherwise use `<input type="button">`

If checked and it is well, then It would be great to add your code here or screenshot of code.